# Can't show Google map using api key

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem to show google map using api key

The console shows :

```
"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https ://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"
```

My Script is like this :

```
script(async='', defer='', src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7E9zHPtSADzjHAsOz7fvQTmplo2XpwWk&callback=initMap')
function initMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: _zom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(_Lat, _Lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: true
    };
}
```

I tried to change the key and i tried both to assign the domain name to the key and also without domain name

PS : When i create the key i choose browser key

Comment: The error you report doesn't make any sense.  You have a key in your API include.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: yes that's confusing it was working before. is there any way to not callback the initmap method next to api key ?

Comment: remove the `async defer` and the callback from the include of the API, then call that initMap `onload`.

Comment: can you demonstrate how to call initmap on load because i tried and i get the error initmap is not a function, thank you alot for your time ;)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/116g7k0e/)

Comment: thaank you very muuch :D it works with you without the api key ??

Comment: An API key is **recommended**, but not required (at least yet).

Comment: thaank you very muuch